# server sent event (SSE) : how to broadcast a message?

Tags: server-sent-events

What I want to achieve is:

```
$.post('events.php', {'message': 'hello world'}, function(res) {
 
});
```

- user1 sends a message to server (a simple POST request)
- server sends broadcasts that message to ALL users that have subscribed to EventSource

Server part is (events.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.

function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
    echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

while(true) {
    $serverTime = time();
    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        sendMsg($serverTime, 'message: ' . date("h:i:s", time()));
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

I tried that infinite loop **while(true)** to avoid that 3 seconds polling.
I also tried without that infinite loop. Only the user who sends the message receives the event.

I understand that approach is not good. But what would be the good practice to use SSE for a chat application ?

How can I send events to ALL users ?

Answer (score 0):

SSE is a dedicated socket and dedicated process per client.

That means your server-side process has basically the same choices as the browser clients: poll or subscribe.

Because your database is likely to be on the same server/LAN as the SSE server process, repeated polling doesn't have the same downsides it does for a browser client. So to do a chat application you could regularly poll a SQL database, that stores chat messages, to see if anything new has arrived.

An example of the *subscribe* approach would be to have each SSE process open a dedicated socket to a chat server, running locally, which will broadcast to each of those SSE listeners each time a new chat message arrives.