# Receiving external data in a Server Sent Event and PHP

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I'm having trouble understanding Server Sent Events, particularly on the server side. All the examples I find are basically just sending the server time, which isn't terribly helpful.

I'm trying to bring data in from an external resource that is sending a POST request to the file, specifically a Twilio webhook whenever a new message is received.

The problem that I'm running into is that the data sent from the webhook isn't accessible from my request to the Server Sent Event, which makes sense when you think about it because they're two different sessions.

I could create create another file for the webhook to access and add the message data to an SQL database each time a new message is received. Then, in the file that is my serves as my EventSource, I could query that data and see if it's changed, but doesn't that seem horrible inefficient to be querying an SQL database every three seconds, even if I am comparing the data using a session variable or something?

Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); // recommended to prevent caching of event data.
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$body = $_REQUEST['Body'];

$finalbody = !empty($body) ? $body : 'nothing to see here...';

echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
echo "data: $finalbody" . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;
ob_flush();
flush();
```

But that obviously doesn't work when you use it as the EventSource because $_REQUEST['Body'] can't be found.

What good is are Server Sent Events if they have to be constantly querying an external source rather than having data sent to them on-demand and then using that data to send the event on it's way?

Am I missing something?

Any insight here would be much appreciated.

Comment: _“Ideally, it would be something like this”_ - doesn’t appear to make too much sense to me to begin with, because there is no _loop_ there in what you have shown. This needs to be a _continuously_ running script, like the example under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#sending_events_from_the_server shows. And _because_ it is running continuously, you can not just have your webhook receiver script “call it”, but you will have to put the data somewhere both scripts have access to.

Comment: @CBroe That's kind of my point, though. Even if this script is continuously running, is the data that's passed from the webhook going to be accessible when called from EventSource without being put into a text file or a database?

Comment: No, not on its own. There is no connection between these two scripts, they do not “share” any data by default. If you want them to, then you have to facilitate that. If you don’t want to do database operations all the time because you fear the performance impact, then look into alternatives such as Shared Memory maybe.

Comment: My answer would be a variation on one I wrote a week ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66590258/841830  I.e. you don't need to constantly query (poll) that external data source; you could instead set up to get push notifications (which are then passed on to the sse client).